# adding a List<Object> to a wpf grid and updating frequently

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I started my wpf learning path!. I have a class with a static list property. I am updating that list from different part of the application. How do I display and frequently update the data grid?

```
public class Customer
    {
        
        public string FirstName{ get; set; };
        public string LastName{ get; set; };
        public int Age{ get; set; };

    
    }

 public static class AllCustomerInfo
    {
        
        public static List<Customer> CustomerList{ get; set; } = new List<Customer>();
    
    }
```

As I don't have any experience, some searching showed me that, data can be added to a grid like this

```
<DataGrid
   x:Name="dataGrid"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

How do I bind this list data to grid. I have customer information from the moment I start the application. So right away I would like to see the data and update whenever I add a new customer.

Comment: For working with WPF, I recommend using the MVVM (model-view-viewmodel) pattern. Basically, you specify a viewmodel (a C# file) and a view (a XAML) file. You then use the viewmodel for the view. In your viewmodel, you create public properties, and in your view, you create bindings to these properties. You should find plenty of information about it by searching the web for "WPF MVVM".

Answer (score 0):

Bind to the property:

```
<DataGrid
   x:Name="dataGrid"
   Grid.Row="0"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:AllCustomerInfo.CustomerList}}"/>
```

...and change its type to `ObservableCollection<Customer>`:

```
public static class AllCustomerInfo
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Customer> CustomerList { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
}
```

Comment: @SofortBalu: Did you try this?